# Can a std::map rebalance during the invocation of a const function?

Tags: c++

I have a `const std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>>` member variable and a function `const std::vector* foo()`. I'd like this function to sometimes return a pointer to an element of this map. But I'm concerned that the map might rebalance - even during a `std::map` function marked `const` - so invalidating my returned pointer. I know that any subsequent modification of the map will invalidate my pointers but that cannot happen as I've marked the member variable `const`.

I can't return a reference as on occasions, `foo` needs to return `nullptr`.

Is what I'm doing safe?

Comment: If the map object itself is const, then what would cause it to rebalance after its initialization?

Comment: Only iterators to erased elements are invalidated (with `map`), insertions do not affect current iterators; hence even if it does rebalance (but it is `const`, so I'm not sure it can even do that), the iterators remain valid.

Comment: @NeilKirk: That's basically what he's asking!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard is quite clear: the only thing that can invalidate
an iterator or a pointer or reference into a map is removing the
element it points to.  You can even insert other elements
without invalidating your pointer.  See §23.2.4/9:

> The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of
>   iterators and references to the container, and the erase members shall
>   invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately the C++11 standard makes this clear:

> §23.2.2/1:
>
> For purposes of avoiding data races (17.6.5.9), implementations shall
>   consider the following functions to be const: begin, end, rbegin,
>   rend, front, back, data, find, lower_bound, upper_bound, equal_range,
>   at and, except in associative or unordered associative containers,
>   operator[].

So you are safe. The `map` cannot rebalance when calling a `const` function.

Comment: What does this have to do with rebalancing, or the validity of iterators or pointers into the map.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean "const std::vector* foo()."

Rebalancing is not relevant here. The answer is that your returned pointer is not invalidated as long as the item to which it points remains in the std::map (and the map is not destroyed or moved).

Note that std::map (which you shouldn't be using anyway - See Chandler's talk at CppCon 2014: http://youtu.be/fHNmRkzxHWs) will never move items once they are added to the container, even when rebalancing. The address of an item in a map will be the same as long as that item is in the container. This is true without regard to rebalancing or additions and/or removal of other items.