# C++ STL Concurrent update to values in fixed size map - Is it safe?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stl, thread-safety

I have a C++ STL map

`std::map < std::thread_id, int > some_map` which has a fixed size of `num_threads` and all locations are initialised to 0 in the beginning.

```
some_map[id1] = 0;
some_map[id2] = 0;
...
```

Question: Is it safe if each thread modifies the container as

`some_map[std::this_thread::get_id()] = rand()` in each of the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26867506/3585575), STL containers are almost uniformly `const` thread-safe, such that calling any `const`-qualified member functions will not result in a data race.  Since `std::map::operator[]` is not a `const`-qualified, thread-safety is not guaranteed.

*Even if* you ensure that you will not be calling thread-unsafe functions (i.e. `insert`, `erase`), unless you understand the underlying implementation for `std::map`, which can depend on the library (GCC, Clang, etc.), be wary of calling `std::map::operator[]` from multiple threads on a shared object.

If you need the map-like behavior, consider using a container that is specifically designed to be thread safe (e.g. Intel's TBB `concurrent_hash_map`).